My C++ linker is failing and I am unable to understand the error: "multiple definition of `main'"
Why is this error message appearing?
From the last few days, I was trying to run a C++ program but the error is showing. I don't understand why. I changed the compiler settings after seeing a YouTube video. It was working until the file name was Main.cpp and when in the next program I gave another name it started showing the error. I do not understand how to read the error messages.
#include <iostream> //iostream allow us to load pre-built libraries.

int main() // main function. Function in c++ is a block of code that does many things.
{
    std::cout << "Hello World ! This is my first C++ project" << std:: endl;
    std::cout << "This is Anish Sharma";
    return 0;
}

Terminal -> Run Task... -> GCC compiler.
Then comes the error message:
* Executing task: Build with GCC compiler 14.2, released [1.8.2024]

Starting build...
cmd /c chcp 65001>nul && C:\mingw64\bin\g++.exe -g -std=c++2b C:\Users\ANISH\Documents\CPP\*.cpp -o C:\Users\ANISH\Documents\CPP\rooster.exe
C:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\ANISH\AppData\Local\Temp\ccME9uEU.o: in function `main':
C:/Users/ANISH/Documents/CPP/new.cpp:3: multiple definition of `main'; C:\Users\ANISH\AppData\Local\Temp\cce2cCLP.o:C:/Users/ANISH/Documents/CPP/main.cpp:2: first defined here
C:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\ANISH\AppData\Local\Temp\ccup70G8.o: in function `main':
C:/Users/ANISH/Documents/CPP/numbersprinting.cpp:4: multiple definition of `main'; C:\Users\ANISH\AppData\Local\Temp\cce2cCLP.o:C:/Users/ANISH/Documents/CPP/main.cpp:2: first defined here
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Build finished with error(s).

* The terminal process terminated with exit code: -1.
* Terminal will be reused by tasks, press any key to close it.


"//iostream allow us to load pre-built libraries...." No that is not what it is for. It's simply a standard header. Fundamentally, it's no different than any other header. A good c++ book.

Are you sure there is only one cpp source file in the directory that has the main function. Also, try deleting all files from the directory or better yet delete this whole directly and then rebuilding your project. And make sure only one source file has a main function.

Because you have multiple main functions defined. One in numbersprinting.cpp, one in new.cpp and one in main.cpp. You can only have one main function. You are compiling all .cpp files. Maybe you intended to only compile numbersprinting.cpp then you should not use *.cpp as argument to the compiler but specify that one file.

My advice is to never use code-runner with c++ or c based code. It doesn't handle more than 1 source file and if you fix it to allow more than 1 source file that fix will break any code you had that was only 1 source file if you have more than 1 cpp file in a folder.

What it is about 'multiple definition of main' is hard to understand? I'm sure you do understand but you are looking at your code and you see one definition of main. The question you haven't asked yourself is 'that's what I think the code is but does the compiler agree?'. If you had asked yourself that question you might have figured out that the compiler has a different opinion of what your code is than you do. This is a vital lesson in learning to use computers. They don't understand you, they do exactly what you tell them to do, even though it might not be what you meant to tell them.

Your compile command:
C:\mingw64\bin\g++.exe -g -std=c++2b C:\Users\ANISH\Documents\CPP*.cpp
Is globbing your directory for C++ files to build. This will attempt to build all files ending with .cpp in the current directory as a single program. It is up to you to ensure that all of these files together make a valid C++ program.
multiple definition of 'main':
This means that the linker encountered an error with multiple definitions of the same function, in this case main. This is likely happening because you have multiple .cpp files in your directory with main functions defined, which isn't allowed. Functions must be unique across your entire program (this is one of the validity rules discussed above).
I suggest either restructuring your project directory such that only .cpp files you want combined together are in the folder, or modifying your compile command to stop globbing the .cpp files, and instead just compile a single file at a time.

It seems that you have multiple .cpp files in your current directory and you are including them one inside another, but every single one have a main() function, which is failing the compilation. Your program should have one and only main() function!
The compiler is clearly saying: "multiple definition of `main'".

You have the main() function first defined in main.cpp on line 2.
You have also defined main() function in new.cpp on line 3.
Then, you have also defined main() function in numbersprinting.cpp on line 4.


And technically, the "compilation" is NOT failing, but the "linking" is failing. Why? Here:

Notice all the .o files in your output (i.e.: ccME9uEU.o, ccup70G8.o, etc.).
It means, the "assembling" stage is passing, hence getting the assembler output files. But (pay attention!) when the compiler tries to "link" (the final stage) together all the different assembly outputs into a single executable binary, it finds out that each individual assembly output file has a main() function.
And as you may know that in C family languages, this main() function is the entry point of your program and as I said earlier, one program should have only one main() function.
That is why the compiler doesn't know which is the "real" main() function, which is the entry point of your program, like do you understand!? And the compiler gives up and "gives" the errors.


I hope all that makes sense. Also, you didn't provided the structure of your project, so I am not sure if you have multiple .cpp source files. So, I suggested all that from your compiler's output. It may be helpful if you can use commands like tree to provide what the structure of your project folder is.

Edited: Also, as the @DXPower said above/below, the cause of this error is the command you are running to compile your program. You are compiling all the .cpp files as one program, even though they don't have anything to do with each other.
